# Function on window.scroll and get the vertical offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
window.scroll=function MyFunc(){
 var y = window.scrollTop();
 alert(y);
}
```

How to call a function when the window is scrolled and how to get the amount of pixels the window has been vertically scrolled. I want to play an animation when a desired value has been reached. Help.

Comment: 2 things you'd like to take into consideration: #1) Is to use requestAnimationFrame (as the window.scroll makes the browser janky while scrolling). #2) Check out IntersectionObserver and a possible polyfill if you want to fire an animation based on an element's display on the viewport.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `window.onscroll` without the use of `jQuery`. That was what you were missing on your code. It should be `window.onscroll` and to get the vertical scroll pixels use `window.scrollY`

```js
window.onscroll = function (e) {
  console.log(window.scrollY);
};
```

```css
html, body{
  height: 2000px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the `window` object in `$()` to use the `scrollTop()` function on it.

```js
$(window).scroll(function MyFunc(e){
 var y = $(window).scrollTop();
 console.log(y);
});
```

```css
html, body{
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In Javascript, you can add an event listener for the scroll event on the window and use [`window.pageYOffset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset) (for better cross-browser compatability) to get the amount of pixels scrolled vertically.

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function MyFunc(e){
  var y = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined)
  ? window.pageYOffset
  : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;//for cross-browser compatability
  console.log(y);
});
```

```css
html, body{
  height: 2000px;
}
```